# Python script for checkout from perforce

Tags: perforce

I want to write the script in python that will check out the particular tool from perforce. It should also notify when there is any checking related to tools.

Comment: And the question is?...

Answer (score 2):

Two separate items, but first, install P4Python.  Once you have that installed, write a python script to do the checkout for you, e.g.,

```
from P4 import P4,P4Exception 
p4 = P4()                     
p4.port = "perforce:1666"
p4.user = "myuser"
p4.client = "myclient"  
p4.connect()                

p4.run("edit", "//depot/alltools/mytool/mytool.txt")
```

For the second task, write a new trigger, e.g.,

```
Triggers:
    toolsubmit change-commit //depot/alltools/... C:\mytriggers\tool_checked_in.py
```

...where the latter part of the path would be the path to "what you want to run" when something is submitted to the //depot/alltools/... part of the depot (in this case, I would have an email sent to interested parties.

Then again, if only interested parties want to know about something like this, they can add the path to the "Reviews" section of their User.

Comment: Thanks @tkosinski

Comment: Hey, i am new to perforce so not getting why p4.client = "myclient" and p4.run("edit", "//depot/alltools/mytool/mytool.txt") are used. Another question is suppose i want to check out any changelist in my local workspace for that also this script work? Please help i am new to perforce.

Comment: Replace "myclient" with the name of your client (aka, workspace) and "//depot/alltools/mytools/mytool.txt" with the depot path to your file.  I'm not sure I understand your second question, but certainly playing around in P4V before jumping into p4python might be worthwhile. Good introductory video: https://www.perforce.com/support/tutorial-video-library/video/basic-operations-p4v

Comment: I want to checkout latest changlist so what i need to do. i want script in python.

Comment: You want to edit the latest changelist? Or you want to get the changes made in the latest changelist?